# How to detect browser in full-screen mode or in react

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I want to show an alert when the browser is in the fullscreen and normal screen. I did something like this.

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange",this.changeWidth());
}

  changeWidth=()=>{
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
    console.log(window.screen.height)
    if( window.innerHeight == window.screen.height) {
      console.log("browser is in full screen")
      alert("browser is in full screen")
    }

    else{
      alert("Browser in normal screen")
    }
  }
```

Alert was only shown when it is in normal mode but it was not shown when the browser is put into fullscreen mode. Can someone tell me a way to make this happened? I found lot of questions regarding using javascript but all those answers tried by me do not seems to work in react. If someone can help me it is a great help.

Comment: try to change `componentDidMount` to 

```
componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange",this.changeWidth);
}
```

because you must pass a callback to the event listener

Comment: @AndreyKhoronko when I put like that this not working in normal mode too

Comment: I think it depends on how you activate fullscreen mode. I found out that `fullscreenchange` event not triggered by F11 keyboard shortcut, but it works with `requestFullscreen` api. Try to request fullscreen from some event, e.g. `document.onclick = () => document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()`

Comment: Also I discovered, that `window.innerHeight != window.screen.height` in the fullscreen mode, check `document.fullscreen` or `document.fullscreenElement` rather. See details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API